# Filter a dataframe between two dates

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe with dates column and some other column. I need to filter based on dates.

DF

```
dates   A   
2018-09 3
2018-10 4
2018-11 2
2018-12 66
2019-01 5
```

here if `criteria_1` is `2018-10` and `criteria_2` is `2018-12` I need to filter the dataframe including those two criteria.

```
data_ <- data_[grep(criteria_1,data_$dates) & grep(criteria_2,data_$dates)]
```

Comment: Don't know why the text comparison answer was deleted - `subset(DF, dates >= "2018-09" & dates <= "2018-12")` works just fine as it is in `year-month` order with leading zeroes, so it should always sort correctly. You most definitely *can* have comparisons between text values: `"b" > "a"` returns `TRUE` for instance.

Comment: @thelatemail You're right but it would be important to clarify that this approach won't work if `DF$dates` are `factor`s.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use `grep` to get row indices and then subset the dataframe.

```
criteria_1 = "2018-10"
criteria_2 = "2018-12"
df[grep(criteria_1, df$dates):grep(criteria_2, df$dates), ]

#   dates  A
#2 2018-10  4
#3 2018-11  2
#4 2018-12 66
```

---

If there are some out-of-range issues we can use `match` instead with proper `nomatch` arguments

```
df[match(criteria_1, df$dates, nomatch = 1):
   match(criteria_2, df$dates, nomatch = nrow(df)), ]
```

So if `crietria_2` is out-of-range by `default` it goes to last row

```
criteria_1 = "2018-10"
criteria_2 = "2018-aa"
df[match(criteria_1, df$dates, nomatch = 1):
   match(criteria_2, df$dates, nomatch = nrow(df)), ]

#    dates  A
#2 2018-10  4
#3 2018-11  2
#4 2018-12 66
#5 2019-01  5
```

and if `criteria_1` is out-of-range we can go to first row by `default` it does to first row

```
criteria_1 = "2018-aa"
criteria_2 = "2018-12"
df[match(criteria_1, df$dates, nomatch = 1):
   match(criteria_2, df$dates, nomatch = nrow(df)), ]

#    dates  A
#1 2018-09  3
#2 2018-10  4
#3 2018-11  2
#4 2018-12 66
```

Comment: `Error in :: argument of length 0` ?

Comment: If my criteria is out of range it is giving this error.. So how to auto assign to last value or first value if I input something out of bound?

Comment: or to show nothing found in other cases like if both values are out of bound?